# Evaluating the sum of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I don't know if this question is trivial but let me put it in the first place. 
I'm trying to find the sum of $\binom{n}{0}^2+\binom{n}{1}^2+\binom{n}{2}^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}^2+\binom{n}{n}^2$ or equivalently $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2$.

How would you proceed?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You should not say that without providing a link, because I am pretty involved in mathematics and I did not know that.

Comment: Agreed. It is equal to $\binom{2n}n$, which can be proved using a combinatorial argument.

Comment: It is $$\frac{2^{2 n} \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   (n+1)}$$

Comment: It is a special case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

Comment: @HackerBoss I didn't get your statement. What link do you want?

Answer (score 1):

lets first prove a more general thing, i.e,

$\sum_{i = 0}^{x} {n \choose i } {m \choose x - i }  = {m + n \choose x}$.

For that, let's suppose we have m apples and n oranges, and now we want to choose x fruits from them, we can do it in ${m + n \choose x}$ ways, and that's RHS. Now we can also select x fruits, by selecting 0 apples and x oranges, 1 apple and x - 1 oranges and so on, and that's exactly LHS, and hence LHS = RHS.

Now just put m = n, and x = n, in the equation, so it becomes

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} {n \choose i}{n \choose n - i} = {2n \choose n}$

or,

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} {n \choose i} {n \choose i} = {2n \choose n}$

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} {n \choose i}^2 = {2n \choose n}$